# Avoid filtering of datalist items in an input element

Tags: html, combobox

I need a combo-box behavior in a web application. I came across the following solution:

```html
<input type="text" list="options" >
<datalist id="options" >
   <option>Asterix</option>
   <option>Obelix</option>
</datalist>
```

However, as soon as any text is entered, Firefox and Chrome only show the user those options that fit to the already entered text. In the example, as soon as the input contains the letter "A", the browser only offers Asterix as an option but hides Obelix.

I would like to show the user all entries of the datalist, regardless of what is written inside the input element. However, I would also like to allow custom inputs. In the example, the user should be able to enter `Methusalix` and when he does, I would like to browser to still show Asterix and Obelix as alternatives. How can this be achieved with HTML5? I'd bet there is some option to allow this behavior, but I can't find it.

I am using this to let the user chose between multiple configuration entries. The user may either chose from the existing configuration entries or create a new one by writing a name that does not exist yet. However, I would like to give the user the option to go back to the existing ones at any time, regardless of how he had named the discarded new one.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni: I edited my question and hope that it is clearer now

Comment: I use as a partial solution `onfocus="this.value=''` on the `input` element - clear the input value and the it shows the dropdown with options. As an improvement you could remember input value and restore it if the user wont select other option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with a customised implementation of [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete).

The library uses its own UI elements so you can change the behaviour of the dropdown by overriding the search and/or response methods so it always returns ALL items.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var data = [
   {label: "Item 1", value: '1'},
   {label: "Item 2", value: '2'}
];

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: function( request, response ) {
      response( data );
  },
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although jQuery UI Autcomplete does work, it seems unfortunate there isn't a setting for input and datalist to simply disable auto filtering. Using jquery-ui introduces new lists and items with special classes (ui-menu, ui-menu-item) that I now have to deal with.

Answer (score 7):

The way you want the suggestions to appear is not described by the specification and is not how autocomplete or suggestions are usually implemented on UI controls.

As you suggest, I think you can only do what you want by coding your very own suggestion UI in javascript, not being dependent on any user-agent choice regarding the user experience.

Comment: Hm, I don't know that many UI libraries in detail, but the Windows API and especially Windows Forms in .NET have this as the default option for combo boxes.

Answer (score 5):

If the user input does not matter I do not see the point of using the `datalist` element.

Instead, you can opt for the classic `select` element that will show all the options (even though the user won't be able to enter text).

```html
<form>
  <select name="options">
    <option>Asterix</option>
   <option>Obelix</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you have a different expected behaviour, like showing the options that do coincide first, please expand your question.

Comment: The user input should not matter for the options that the browser would display, but it should still be possible to enter anything previously not in the list.

Comment: Well if you have a large dataset you want to filter on input. The classic select is not good UX for this.

Answer (score 0):

Partial js solution, supporting both filtering and complete list.

> onfocus="this.value.trim()!=''?this.setAttribute('placeholder',this.value):'';this.value='';"

Basically, if value is already set, onfocus sets it as placeholder and clears the input field for typing, showing complete options list. Then as you type, filters apply.