# Hide datalist options when user starts typing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a datalist that shows the saved data of the user when he/she closed the program. I wanted the datalist to only show when the user clicks on the dropdown arrow (or the input box) and hides when the user starts typing. I've tried:

1. Creating an `oninput` event in the hopes that the datalist will hide when user starts typing.
2. Hiding datalist by using `datalist.style.display = none;`
3. Trying the codes written here: [Avoid filtering of datalist items in an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678677/avoid-filtering-of-datalist-items-in-an-input-element) (Although it does not work in my case because I need to use pure JS)

Help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**
Here is my code:

```
<div style="top:60px;position:absolute;z-index:2" id="speechBox">
    <input id ="userText" name="userText" type="text" list = 'talk-list' oninput = "hideList()"></input>
    <span class = "dropdown" title = "Saved Talk"><datalist id = 'talk-list'></datalist></span>
    <button id="speakText" class="toolbutton" title="Speak"></button>
  <hr>
</div>

<script>
    function hideList() {
        var hiddenList = document.getElementById("talk-list");
        hiddenList.style.display = none;
    }
</script>
```

Note: The datalist is not empty. I have an external script that adds infinite amount of options to datalist.

Comment: Can you present any code? Can you not add a `keypress` or equivalent event handler to apply the `display`? It's all a bit vague...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. If possible, the relevant portion of your code (html/js) running on a snippet. Right now, all we can do is guesswork

Comment: I've edited my question to show the codes.

Comment: What is the point of having a datalist at all if you want to hide it when user types? That is when it shows by default. When would you expect it to show?

Comment: @charlietfl I expected the datalist to show if and only if the user clicks on the input box. When the user starts typing, the datalist hides (will not suggest words, or filter the content).

Comment: Just tested it now. @charlietfl is right. The `datalist` element natively behaves to show options as the user types, filtering those that are relevant to the current input. What's the point of a datalist if you want to hide it then. I doubt you can override this behavior. Better yet just use an improvised datalist using a div and manipulate it as you like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you can do this is to chage the datalist id when there is a value in input. If there is no value then change the id back so that they can choose the options in the datalist rather than type a new one.

```js
function hideList(input) {
 var datalist = document.querySelector("datalist");
 if (input.value) {
  datalist.id = "";      
 } else {
  datalist.id = "talk-list";
 }
}
```

```html
<input id ="userText" name="userText" type="text" list = 'talk-list' oninput="hideList(this)"></input>
    <span class = "dropdown" title = "Saved Talk"><datalist id = 'talk-list'><option>Apple</option><option>Ball</option><option>Calculator</option><option>Donkey</option></datalist></span>
    <button id="speakText" class="toolbutton" title="Speak">Speak</button>
```

Comment: After backspace if no text is there, list disappears. Any workaround to show list after user press backspace.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can replace how the `<datalist>` element behaves. If I were you, I'd just make my own datalist made out of divitis. The sample below still has ways to go, but this should get you started in case you want to go this path.

The 3rd solution you mentioned in your post is not really a direct solution to your datalist problem. Instead it suggests a separate library that can render a datalist-like ui element, which turns out to be something from jQuery. What I'm suggesting is exactly like that, except you're gonna write your own.

```js
function hideList() {
const list = document.querySelector("#talk-list");
list.style.display = "none";
}
      
function showList(){
const list = document.querySelector("#talk-list");
list.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#talk-list{ border: 1px solid #ccc; display: none; }
button{display: block}
```

```html
<div style="top:60px;position:absolute;z-index:2" id="speechBox">
  <input id ="userText" name="userText" type="text" list = 'talk-list' oninput = "hideList()" onclick="showList()"></input>
   <div id = 'talk-list'>
      <div value="foo">foo</div>
      <div value="bar">bar</div>
   </div>
  <button id="speakText" class="toolbutton" title="Speak">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not condemning you for a UI that acts as OP wants. Whole concept though seems so backwards , counter intuitive and not very user friendly

Comment: @charlietfl Literally why it has a long ways to go. You don't expect this to be just this?

Comment: Understood. i'm the one that asked what the whole point of datalist is in comments above. And as I said you are doing what OP was asking for...it's what they are asking for that doesn't make sense and is counter intuitive

Comment: @AndreaG. but why hide it? As user types they don't have to type every letter as clickable options get filtered which is how users are accustomed to seeing such autocomplete interfaces

Comment: @charlietfl I know, but I wanted to disable the filtering effect of datalist. But I have to do it using JS only. Is it possible, or do I have to use another combo box tags?

Comment: @AndreaG. probably not. A datalist is like a `<select>` with regard to it's behaviors are managed by the browser itself not javascript. Can't do much with either of them.

Comment: @AndreaG. If you strictly have to implement that kind of behavior. You have no choice but to use a custom element, which you can get from other libraries or you can write your own.

Comment: @charlietfl It is kind of counter-productive for the programmer's side, but like you said, I'm just giving what OP is asking for. But if OP strictly needs what she is asking for, it is completely possible to make this custom ui element intuitive and friendly for the users.

Comment: @AbanaClara agree about making it do what OP wants. To me though users are so used to how autocomplete ui's work which is to me what makes it unfriendly as they now have to type full words and worry about typos. Just goes against the grain of conventional UX

Comment: @charlietfl Sadly. I think OP is obligated to do this. I agree about the user experience matter and basically how the default datalist works is how an autocomplete element is supposed to work -- but if OP is tasked to do this and there's just no way to reason this out, she has no other choice. If she's doing this on just her own, I would also suggest she drop what she's asking for