# How to make a datalist-enabled HTML INPUT with a default value still show alternatives when clicked?

Tags: html, web, browser, html-datalist

After learning about the wonderful `datalist` feature in HTML 5 today, I have converted all my old messy combined `input` and `select` nightmares into `datalist`-enabled inputs. Works well except for one "small" detail:

Whenever my `datalist`-enhanced `input` has a default value, for example `... value="USD"`, it seems like it completely hides the list of options! This leaves the user in the dark about alternatives, just because I wanted the most common default to be displayed in the `input`, to save the user's time.

At first, I thought I had a bug in my own code, but as soon as I removed the `value` attribute for the `input`, it does indeed list all the currencies (that's what my field is for) that I have defined in the `datalist`.

Why can't I have a default value while still allowing the user to select from the list? I truly hope I'm just missing something obvious.

I've tried reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 0):

According to [the `list` attribute specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-list), it allows listing **suggestions** (rather than options).

Accordingly, browser vendors seem to have implements the *auto-complete pattern* where all suggestions are always filtered by the current value. The primary interaction is to type. To get all suggestions again requires the user to delete their value (typing again).

With a value, users still can open the list by means of the arrow-down key, but it will be filtered.

This is how auto-complete works most of the time, you can try f.e. on [Material Angular’s Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples).

Interestingly, the standard makes it an option not to filter in all cases:

> User agents are encouraged to filter the suggestions represented by the suggestions source element when the number of suggestions is large …

But browser vendors don’t seem to have gone for this option. See also [Avoid filtering of datalist items in an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678677/avoid-filtering-of-datalist-items-in-an-input-element) for some confirmation on the theory

So I guess the best solution for your case would be to add an empty button next to the input. You could trigger opening the `datalist` in browsers that support it by means of `showPicker()`:

```html
    <label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
    <input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

    <datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
            <option value="Chocolate">
            <option value="Coconut">
            <option value="Mint">
            <option value="Strawberry">
            <option value="Vanilla">
        </datalist>

    <button onclick="empty()" aria-label="Empty ice cream flavor">×</button>
```

```js
    function empty() {
      const i = document.getElementById('ice-cream-choice');
      i.value = "";

      if ('showPicker' in HTMLInputElement.prototype) {
        i.showPicker()
      }
    }
```

Btw if the input has a default value, it should clearly show it’s value without interacting with it.

```
<input value="USD" list="currencies">US Dollar</option>
```

Comment: But the whole thing with `datalist` was for me to *avoid* JavaScript messes, and to make it all "native and familiar and clean"... :(

Comment: Well, you have the assumption that deleting text that is already inside the input poses troubles to users when trying to change value, to get their job done. I would suppose to observe some real users work with your new version to see if that’s actually the case. (: